# Разница между X-Some-Header и Some-Header

Tags: http, header

Где-то вычитал, что заголовки с приставкой `X` отличаются от обычных... 
Вопрос: это действительно так? Если да, - чем они отличаются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно общей конвенции, префикс `X-` используется для нестандартных расширений. Таким образом, заголовки `X-`, как правило, являются узкоспециализированными и не используются клиентами общего назначения для принятия каких-либо логических решений: Location вместе с 302 будет заставлять клиент совершать новый запрос, Expires может предотвратить последующие запросы к ресурсу, а какой-нибудь X-Parent-Entity-URL обрабатываться не будет (хотя по этому урлу может оказаться важная информация в контексте текущего ресурса).

Сама конвенция распространяется далеко не только на HTTP-заголовки, поэтому вы можете встретить ее в совсем других местах.